# CSS content overflowing containing div

Tags: html, css

Currently have a problem with some DIVs overlapping their containing DIVs. See image below (the 3 products at the bottom):

[image]

All the body content of the page  is held within the #content DIV:

```
div#content {
    width: 960px;
    float: left;
    background-image: url("../img/contentBg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    border-top: 8px solid #5E88A2;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
}
```

And here is the CSS for the product boxes within the #content div:

```
.upper {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
div#products {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
div.productContainer {
    float: left;
    width: 265px;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-left: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    text-align: right;
}

div.product {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
div.product p {
}
div.product a {
    display: block;
}
div.product img {
    float: left;
}
div.product img:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 80);
}
div.transparent {
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 80);
}
```

And here is the HTML for the boxes:

```
        <div class="productContainer">
            <div class="product">
                <h2 class="upper center">A2 Print</h2>

                <a href='../edit/?productId=5&amp;align=v' class='upper'>                   <img src="../../wflow/tmp/133703b808c91b8ec7e7c7cdf19320b7A2-Print.png" alt="Representation of image printed at A2 Print through Website." /></a>
                <p class="upper">16.5 inches x 23.4 inches<br /><strong>&pound;15.99</strong></p>
                <p class="upper smaller"><em><span><span class="yes">Yes</span> - your picture quality is high enough for this size</span>                  </em></p>

                <p><a href='../edit/?productId=5&amp;align=v' class='upper'><span>Select</span></a></p>                 
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="productContainer">
            <div class="product transparent">
                <h2 class="upper center">A1 Print</h2>
                <a href='../edit/?productId=11&amp;align=v' class='upper'>                  <img src="../../wflow/tmp/133703b808c91b8ec7e7c7cdf19320b7A1-Print.png" alt="Representation of image printed at A1 Print through Website." /></a>
                <p class="upper">23.4 inches x 33.1 inches<br /><strong>&pound;19.99</strong></p>
                <p class="upper smaller"><em><span><span class="no">Warning</span> - your picture quality may not be sufficient for this size</span>                    </em></p>


                <p><a href='../edit/?productId=11&amp;align=v' class='upper'><span>Select</span></a></p>                    
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="productContainer">
            <div class="product transparent">
                <h2 class="upper center">Poster Print (60cm x 80cm)</h2>
                <a href='../edit/?productId=12&amp;align=v' class='upper'>                  <img src="../../wflow/tmp/133703b808c91b8ec7e7c7cdf19320b7Poster-Print-(60cm-x-80cm).png" alt="Representation of image printed at Poster Print (60cm x 80cm) through Website." /></a>
                <p class="upper">23.6 inches x 31.5 inches<br /><strong>&pound;13.95</strong></p>

                <p class="upper smaller"><em><span><span class="no">Warning</span> - your picture quality may not be sufficient for this size</span>                    </em></p>

                <p><a href='../edit/?productId=12&amp;align=v' class='upper'><span>Select</span></a></p>                    
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any idea what could be causing these DIVs to overlap? What I'd like is for all the boxes to fit within the #container div as expected. It's driving me crazy!

Cheers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Did you try to set to the footer

```
clear:both;
```

Also, set to the #content

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Comment: Thanks steweb -- adding the following has solved it:

adding overflow:hidden; to div#products
and
setting div.productContainer to height:auto;

Cheers!

Comment: After trying to fix a layout with a 100% height (like the above ex) and an overflowing dynamically added list, this was the only solution that worked out of dozens I tried on SO. Thank you good sir!
I understand why ``clear:both`` works, but I wish I knew why ``overflow:hidden`` works for the content div while not hiding the actual overflowing text of the child div. CSS so complex :/

Answer (score 3):

Add overflow: auto; in your content div CSS :)

Comment: wouldnt that add a scrollbar to the content div? Using overflow:hidden is probably a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Something a lot of people use is called clearfix. here is the code:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content:".";
    display:block;
    height:0;
    clear:both;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.clearfix {display:inline-block;}
/* Hide from IE Mac \*/
    .clearfix {display:block;}
/* End hide from IE Mac */
```

To use this you just add the class clearfix to container. You will probably want to add it to whatever div is containing all the "productContainer"